# Send Audio File to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm sure this is pretty straightforward but basically I have an audio file, and all I want to do is send it to the client.

```
    [HttpPost("text-to-speech")]
    [Produces("audio/mpeg")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TextToSpeech()
    {
        var file = new FileStream("...//845d84df-43ef-4949-882d-81c323cda6a3.mp3", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        return new FileStreamResult(file, "audio/mpeg");
    }
```

It will actually send some data mainly the content length, but never sends the audio of the file to play.  I'm sure this has to do with me needing to build a buffer file of some sorts, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.
[image]

I am also getting a

> 'file.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
> 'System.InvalidOperationException'

this is on the line of

> var file = new Filestream(...)

Comment: Are you sure the file is a valid MP3 file?

Comment: Yeah it's valid, I can open it up and listen to it.  I did have to double check though.

Comment: And have you tried downloading it to the client machine as a file and playing it from there,r athe than in Postman?

Comment: I'm using Swagger, so the image posted should be a playable button.  I just noticed I am getting a read timeout error, I think I'm not creating/disposing of this correctly.  I'll update the card.

Comment: How large is the file? Have you tried downloading it using Chrome etc?

Comment: 24 kilobytes, so fairly small.  I am just running everything locally right now, so the swagger page spawns from my local machine, and the file is locally hosted on my machine.